# .replace to replace input letters with symbols

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to make everything the user enters capitalized and certain letters to be replaced with numbers or symbols. Im trying to utilize .replace but something is not going right. Im not sure what im doing wrong?

```
public class Qbert
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //variables
        String str;
        //get input
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(" Please Enter a Word:");
        //accept input
        str = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.print("" );
        System.out.println(str.toUpperCase()//make all letters entered uppercase
        //sort specific letters to make them corresponding number, letter, or symbol
            + str.replace("A,@")+ str.replaceChar("E","3")+ str.replaceChar ("G","6")
            + str.replaceChar("I","!")+ str.replaceChar("S","$")+ str.replaceChar ("T","7"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the out you are getting ? and what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I am not getting any outs. I'm getting an error that : no suitable method found for replace and that its not applicable.  Ultimately I am trying for any letter entered to be capitalized and the 6 letters a e g i s t to be different symbols. I've got the uppercase taken care.

Comment: @J.j.Crux edited the answer to fit your purpose :)

Comment: Ahh I see now, you're making a l33t speak converter :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    // variables
    String str;
    // get input
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(" Please Enter a Word:");
    // accept input
    str = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.print("");
    System.out.println(str.toUpperCase()); // Upper Case

    System.out.println(str.toUpperCase().replace("A", "@").replace("E", "3")
            .replace("E", "3").replace("G", "6").replace("I", "!").replace("S", "$").replace("T", "7") );

}
```

This should work like you want it to. Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, Strings are immutable. This means that modifying a string will result in a new string. E.g.

`str.replace("a", "b");`

this will replace all the occurrences of 'a' to 'b' in a new string. Original string will remain unaffected. So, to apply the formatting on the actual string, we will have to write:

`str = str.replace("a", "b");`

Similarly, if we want to do multiple replacements then, we need to append replace calls together, e.g.

`str = str.replace("a","b").replace("c", "d");`

Going by this, if you want to perform the substitution, the last system.out in your code will be:

```
System.out.println(str.toUpperCase().replace("A","@").replace("E","3")
    .replace("G","6").replace("I","!").replace("S","$").replace("T","7"));
```

Comment: But he's immediately outputting the string, so it's fine. It may not be apparent from the code, since there's a comment inbetween the `println` and `+` (string concatenation)

Comment: Good explanation. Adding minor formatting to the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) doesn't have a `replaceChar` method. You probably wanted to use method `replace`.

And [`String.replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) takes 2 arguments:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
>   replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
>   example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
>   "ba" rather than "ab".

You have written `str.replace("A,@")+...` instead of `str.replace("A","@")+...`, and so on

One more thing - use a good IDE like Eclipse or Intellij IDEA, they will highlight the parts of your code where you have errors.

Answer (score 0):

> As you want to make multiple changes to the same string, you just use
>   str.toUpperCase().replace().replace().... This means you are giving
>   the output of str.toUpperCase() to the first replace function and so
>   on...

```
         System.out.println(str.toUpperCase()
                               .replace("A","@")
                               .replace("E","3")
                               .replace("G","6")
                               .replace("I","!")
                               .replace("S","$")
                               .replace("T","7"));
```